# How to convert an uploaded image to base64 and decode it back, and save the file as PNG?

Tags: django

I'm creating an image upload page which allows users to upload pages. When a user uploads an image, I want to convert that image using base64 and decode it back to a new image and save it in a PNG format extension. How do I do this?

You can view my current **models.py** code:

```
from django.db import models
import os
from PIL import Image
from datetime import date
import datetime
from .validators import validate_file_extension
import base64

def get_directory_path(instance, filename):

    today = date.today()
    t = datetime.datetime.now() 
    day, month, year = today.day, today.month, today.year
    hour, minutes, seconds = t.hour, t.minute, t.second
    filename = str(day) + str(month) + str(year) + str(hour) + str(minutes) + str(seconds) + '.png'
    dir = 'media'
    path = '{0}/{1}'.format(dir, filename)
    return path

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to = get_directory_path, default = 'media/sample.png', validators=[validate_file_extension])
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: Do you want to just save the image as png or you really need to do those encoding, decoding?

Comment: I aimed to encode an image and decode it back to a newly png format but that wasn't possible so I just saved the image as png. If you know how to do the encoding process using the code above, please do let me know